# Latency on iOS - HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: ios, curl, nsurlconnection, latency

I have built a class which computes the http latency from a given url (note I don't want an ICMP ping, I need the http latency).

My system is based on a `NSURLConnection`, so when the delegate method `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` is called, I initialise a `NSTimer` (the timer is restarted if the connection is redirected again), and as soon as I get the call `connection:didReceiveResponse:` I take the time as the latency.

As far as I know, that should give a good approximation of the http latency, however results are quite far away from the results I get running it from the terminal:

```
curl -I -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total}\\n  http://google.com
```

Actually, which is even weirder, https latencies to the same server (ie. https://google.com) are even faster than http ones (just few ms, but faster). When comparing https latency results with the results I get running a `curl` from the terminal, they are quite close, however http latencies don't seem to be working fine.

I am running the code on iOS 9, allowing arbitrary loads, and I wonder if iOS is trying to redirect or adding any overhead to the http request that makes them slower.

Any clue about this would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the results are correct as http://google.com redirects to the https version. Your timer gets resetted since you're redirect and doesn't take into account the DNS needed for the DNS query.
Maybe you should try websites that don't redirect to https like 9gag.

Comment: On `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` I can see just one redirection, from `http://google.com` to `http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=...`, but it doesn't seem to redirect to an https

Comment: can the gap be caused by the get parameters at the end of the url ?

Comment: I get the same redirection when running a `curl`, however, curl shows a latency much lower (about 15 ms vs 80 ms)